# problem with Flutter SDK location after install with ubuntu snap

Tags: linux, android-studio, flutter, ubuntu

I installed flutter SDK using ubuntu "snap" by running:

`$ sudo snap install flutter --classic`

and when i want to add PATH of flutter sdk to android studio
i have a seroius problem !!

recently i searched flutter sdk paths and i saw some guys said , if you installed it with snap,
this is sdk path:

`/home/user_name/snap/flutter/common/flutter`

then I checked this path and i saw in common directory i have a zip file and there is no flutter directory , i tried to unzip that file but it gives error and cannot unzip it.

please help me , please ....

Comment: ```Initializing Flutter
Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_1.22.4-stable.tar.xz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   193  100   193    0     0    286 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   285
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Flutter initialization failed
Could not find working copy of Flutter```

Comment: when i run **flutter doctor** command, it gives me this error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem happened to me, i solved it by uninstalling the flutter by snap and then following the installation on the website by downloading the .tar file

```
sudo snap remove flutter
```

After uninstalling the flutter with the snap follow the manual installation step of the link

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux

Answer (score 1):

Once you install flutter using snapd, make sure you run `flutter sdk-path` to have your flutter path initialized and the process completes successfully. Otherwise, if the process is terminated without completion, your OS won't recognize flutter.

Comment: You are **not** able to run the `flutter sdk-path` command because it starts to download the flutter SDK from https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/ URI instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was solved by restarting the computer. **Simply**.

Comment: Restarting the computer is not solved the problem for Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the last version of Flutter manually, For more details, [checkout the official docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#install-flutter-manually)
2. Delete all files located in this path: `/home/user_name/snap/flutter/common/flutter`
3. Extract all files from the downloaded `.tar.xz` to the flutter folder

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the latest .tar file for flutter
2. delete all the folders in home/snap/flutter/common/flutter/...
3. Extract the downloaded .tar inside the current directory

Answer (score -1):

Using Flutter with superuser it worked for me.
e.g
sudo flutter sdk-path
sudo flutter doctor